# Javascript linking a function to the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am to invoke a timer using the click of a button. 
**Function for timer:**

```
function countDown(seconds, elem){
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+seconds+ " seconds";

    if(seconds < 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML ='<h2> You can let Go, Frist Responders have been informed</h2>';
    }
    seconds--;

    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+seconds+',"'+elem+'")',1000); 
}
```

**Function call:**

```
document.querySelector('body').onClick = countDown(5,"para");
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper" id="butt2">
<button id="butt" class="fade-in-fwd" >SOS</button>
</div>

<p id="para"></p>
```

This starts running the timer as soon as the webpage loads. How do I limit this

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of issues in your code:

1. `onClick` should be written as `onclick`
2. `onclick` requires a function that will be triggered on click. Since you have assigned `countDown(5,"para")` in the `onclick`, it is invoked immediately.

```js
document.querySelector('body').onclick = function(){
  countDown(5,"para");
}
function countDown(seconds, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Please wait for " + seconds + " seconds";

  if (seconds < 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    element.innerHTML = '<h2> You can let Go, Frist Responders have been informed</h2>';
  }
  seconds--;

  var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + seconds + ',"' + elem + '")', 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="butt2">
  <button id="butt" class="fade-in-fwd">SOS</button>
</div>

<p id="para"></p>
```

> **Note** that there will be weird behaviour with this code if you click multiple times as timer is reinitialized without clearing the previous one so you need to handle that too.